# Get String between two strings - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, substring

I got a function that returns string between two strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Chars (@String VARCHAR(50), @FirstSpecialChar VARCHAR(50), @LastSpecialChar VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @FirstIndexOfChar INT,
         @LastIndexOfChar INT,
         @LengthOfStringBetweenChars INT 

   SET @FirstIndexOfChar   = CHARINDEX(@FirstSpecialChar,@String,0) 
   SET @LastIndexOfChar   = CHARINDEX(@LastSpecialChar,@String,@FirstIndexOfChar+1)
   SET @LengthOfStringBetweenChars = @LastIndexOfChar - @FirstIndexOfChar -1

   SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,@FirstIndexOfChar+1,@LengthOfStringBetweenChars)

   RETURN @String
END
```

However, when I try to get string between POINTDESCRIPTION and DATAPOINT, I get error:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
declare @table table 
(string varchar(50))

insert into @table
select 'EVENT: ID Order Reassignment (Individual Job Specific Update)|||LOCATION: Reassign.reassign()|||DATEPOINTDESCRIPTION: Only specific ID orders were reassigned from user fatis to user blake.|||DATAPOINT: blake' union all
select 'EVENT: ID Order Reassignment (Individual Job Specific Update)|||LOCATION: Reassign.reassign()|||DATAPOINTDESCRIPTION: Only specific ID orders were reassigned from user ilevic to user manic2.|||DATAPOINT: manic2' union all
select 'EVENT: ID Order Reassignment (Individual Job Specific Update)|||LOCATION: Reassign.reassign()|||DATAPOINTDESCRIPTION: Only specific ID orders were reassigned from user links to user sepir.|||DATAPOINT: sepir'
select dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Chars (Tab.string,'POINTDESCRIPTION: ','|||DATAPOINT')
FROM @table Tab

Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
    Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Does anyone see why this would happen?

Comment: My bad :/ I fixed it by increasing length of string in temp table: declare @table table 
(string varchar(500))

Comment: Haha happens with me everytime!

Comment: I did notice a flaw in my function: SET @FirstIndexOfChar   = CHARINDEX(@FirstSpecialChar,@String,0)  that zero should be length of first found char, I think

Comment: Nope. Not required.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds it useful, here is final function to return string between 2 strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Chars (@String VARCHAR(500), @FirstSpecialChar VARCHAR(500), @LastSpecialChar VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @FirstIndexOfChar INT,
         @LastIndexOfChar INT,
         @LengthOfStringBetweenChars INT 
   SET @FirstIndexOfChar   = CHARINDEX(@FirstSpecialChar,@String,0) 
   SET @LastIndexOfChar   = CHARINDEX(@LastSpecialChar,@String,@FirstIndexOfChar+1)
   SET @LengthOfStringBetweenChars = @LastIndexOfChar - @FirstIndexOfChar -1
   SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,@FirstIndexOfChar+LEN(@FirstSpecialChar),@LengthOfStringBetweenChars)
   RETURN @String
END
GO
```

And to call it:

```
select dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Chars (tab.someString,'POINTDESCRIPTION: ','|||DATAPOINT')
FROM yourTable tab
```